# Configure Logstash to receive data from socket and insert it into Elasticsearch in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, logstash

I want to inject data directly to ElasticSearch to perform some performance tests. My first thought was to create JSON file for each document and import the files into ElasticSearch, but it will take too long. I tested 110K files and it took 18 min only to create the files, I need 55M documents - that's 500 times what I tested. Quick calculation: it will take 150 hours, or 6.25 days, that's too long.
Second option is stop when I have the JSON in a stirng and inject the string into ElasticSearch using Logstash. But, I get an exception:

```
2019-12-16 13:49:27,240 | Timer-0 | ERROR | search-injector | c.n.es.injector.output.SocketOutput | SocketOutput::output: 
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:134)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:276)
at com.beniregev.es.injector.output.SocketOutput.output(SocketOutput.java:39)
at com.beniregev.es.injector.policies.UpdateOutputHandlers.run(UpdateOutputHandlers.java:60)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

**ElasticSearch** is running on *localhost* port 9200, *Logstash* is running on *localhost* port 9600. 
My SocketOutput.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketOutput implements OutputHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketOutput.class);

    public static final String CLI_OPTION = "socket";

    @Value("${socket.hostname}")
    private String hostname;
    @Value("${socket.port}")
    private int port;
    Socket clientSocket;

    public boolean open() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("", ioe);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void output(String data) {

        DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
        try {
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outToServer.writeBytes( data );
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("", ioe);
        }
    }

}
```

logstash-simple.conf

```
# Simple Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Stdin -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.
input { stdin { } }

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am running Logstash with this command: `bin/logstash.bat -f config/logstash-simple.conf`

The JSON string is created and is valid, the `Socket` gets correct parameters values (hostname="localhost" and port=9600).
I will appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several layers for the solution, starting with creating and using the correct index in `Elastic Search` using Kibana Manager, then configuring `Logstash` properly, and last is using a JSON string instead of the file.

Creating an index is not the issue of this question, so I will not get into it.

**Logstash.conf (configuration file):**

```
#################################################
# Stdin -> Logstash -> Elastic Search pipeline.
#################################################
input {
    stdin{}
    tcp{
        host => "localhost"
        port => 9600
        codec => json
    }
}

filter 
{
   mutate 
    {
        remove_field => ["host", "@version", "@timestamp", "port", "tags", "level", "logger_name", "themessage", "mensage", "spring.application.name", "level_value", "thread_name"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug }

     elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => ["my-index"]
     }
}
```

**NOTE:** in `index` you enter the name of the index you created and will use.

Running `Logstash` with the configuration file: `bin/logstash.bat -f config/logstash-simple.conf`

Outputing the string to Logstash in Java:

```
package com.beniregev.injector.output;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketOutput implements OutputHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketOutput.class);

    public static final String CLI_OPTION = "socket";
    private int outputIndex = 0;

    @Value("${socket.hostname}")
    private String hostname;
    @Value("${socket.port}")
    private int port;
    Socket clientSocket;

    public boolean open() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("", ioe);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void output(String data) {
        DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
        try {
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outToServer.writeBytes( data );
            outputIndex++;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("", ioe);
        }
        System.out.println("Wrote segment " + outputIndex + " to socket");

    }

}
```

`host` and `port` are to **Logstash**, by default port=9600.

This resolved the problem for me.